# Running Linux Live OS on ARM embedded device

Tags: boot, embedded, live-usb, sd-card

I own an embedded device with **ARM920T** SoC (https://pdf.dzsc.com/ARM/ARM920T.pdf)

The device is in good shape but the OS (Windows Embedded CE 6.0) was corrupted and does not start anymore (actually it is my mistake, I accidentally deleted a file from it).

Can I install a Linux to this device or at least run some Linux Live OS from SD card or USB, Ethernet?

On regular PC I simply inserted a CD with Linux Live OS into drive, the PC booted up and I choose Linux from menu and then reinstalled the system.

Is something similar available for embedded devices? And what Linux image is suitable for my device?

P.S. The device is ZKTECO Biopad 100 if it helps
[[image: device 1]

Comment: According to [this](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/solved-unidentifiable-soc-zkteco-biopad-100-windows-embedded-ce.146685/), it appears to be based on the ARM architecture. There is also some mention of an SDK there, but no link.

Comment: I see an easily accessible JTAG there, which could maybe even be used to fix the original Windows system. Unless you find instructions from the device's manual or manufacturer, you might need to resort to some hacking. Note that you are certainly voiding your warranty for this device, if you have any, or even committing a crime, depending on where you live.

Comment: @Zip: fixing Windows is enough for me, can you provide me more instructions how to usee JTAG?

Comment: Booting Linux on an embedded device is often not that straightforward. I would start by trying to figure out the boot process/boot loader. Does anything show up on the screen when you turn the device on? Is there maybe a pin header that could be serial port (with 4 pins or so)? In any case you will have to retrieve the files you deleted. Maybe you can find a firmware/Windows upgrade image or something online.

Comment: What is that big metal thing on the left? Is that an SD card slot? Is the OS on an SD card? That would make everything a lot easier of course.

Comment: @EzraBühler yes, it is a slot for SD card, but this device run without it. I inserted the SD card into slot wit copied NK.bin file on it but nothing happened.

Comment: Where did you get NK.bin from?

Comment: Maybe you need to flip some switches to make it boot from SD. Are that dip switches below the SD card slot?